# React. Two buttons in a component but only one button works

Tags: reactjs

I am practicing React basics.
I have a component mapped from an array of objects and it shows twice in my website but only on the second time the button works. the first button does not seem to be recognised.

Can someone explain why please? I can't find a reason for this but I am sure it is something obvious I am missing

[A link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/12vblanco/states/draft/interesting-https?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl866x1db0009lpg5cov70a0d%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl866x2kr000k3b6h0uq9w5qr%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl866xqgi007g3b6hwn9jo46y%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cl866xnfh005i3b6hgy0sonwx%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D)

App.js

```
import MainComponent from "./components/MainComponent";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MainComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

---

MainComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import TextItem from "./TextItem";

const text = [
  {
    image:
      "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/626298192418607105/4KBKHQWi_400x400.jpg",
    title: "This is a whale",
    subtitle: "It is a large mammal",
    price: "£ 167.87 + VAT",
    uom: "per Unit",
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://news.artnet.com/app/news-upload/2019/01/Cat-Photog-Feat-256x256.jpg",
    title: "This is a cat",
    subtitle: "It is a small mammal",
    price: "£ 17.87 + VAT",
    uom: "per Unit",
  },
];

const MainComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text.map((eachText, i) => (
        <TextItem
          key={i}
          image={eachText.image}
          title={eachText.title}
          subtitle={eachText.subtitle}
          price={eachText.price}
          uom={eachText.uom}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainComponent;
```

---

TextItem.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

const TextItem = (props) => {
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
  };

  return (
    <Card>
      <DivFlex>
        <ImgDiv>
          <img src={props.image} alt={"a whale"} />
        </ImgDiv>
        <TitleDiv>
          <h1>{props.title}</h1>
          <h3>{props.subtitle}</h3>
        </TitleDiv>
        <PriceDiv>
          <h2>{props.price}</h2>
          <h2>{props.uom}</h2>
        </PriceDiv>
        <EditDiv>
          <Button onClick={onClickHandler}>Edit this</Button>
        </EditDiv>
      </DivFlex>
    </Card>
  );
};

const DivFlex = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
`;

const ImgDiv = styled.div`
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-right: 3%;

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
`;

const TitleDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 3%;
`;
const PriceDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 3%;
`;
const EditDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 3%;
`;
const Button = styled.div`
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: maroon;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.8rem;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export default TextItem;
```

Comment: Hi Rigoz13. Can you reproduce this on codesandbox and share the link? Would be easier for us to help with that.

Comment: Works fine at https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-shadow-jv1tyi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yea. The code above looks fine to me. Can you compare your local code with the code in sandbox and try to see if you can find anything not matching.

Comment: I uploaded the local code to github and linked it from github to sandbox. I see i works in sandbox but it does not in my browser. No idea why

Answer (score 2):

This is happening due to the conflicting heights of `Card` and `DivFlex`. The `Card` has an height of `140px` but its child `DivFlex` has a height of `600px`. So, the next item is basically overlapping the previous item and hence you are not able to click the first button. You can observe the same behaviour if you had any number of items. Only the last item would be clickable due to it overlapping on top of previous item.

One way to fix this is to remove the height from `Card` component and change the height of `DivFlex` to `140px` instead.

PS: It didn't happen in the replica sandbox because you didn't use the `Card` component there and used a regular `div` which by default has a height of `auto`